# Mute/Unmute Sound For All Game Scenes by pressing Button

Tags: unity, sound

My Question is simple i just want to Mute/Pause All Sound of the Game having different scenes.

[image]

From Scene 1 Which is a Main Menu I Have Two Button On/Off .
When i press On Button it stops or mute full game sound or music like Car sound etc in all Scenes.
When i press off button then Sound become active again in all scenes ..

I'm new in this field so please give me some help My Game is almost Complete But i can not Control or Mute All scene Sound at the same time..Waiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply saving the audio volume to `PlayerPrefs` and then loading it on every scene should do the trick:

```
// When off is pressed
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("volume", 0.0F);

// In every scene
AudioListener.volume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("volume");
```

To enable the volume simply change the volume value to something larger than 0.

Comment: thank you brother ....    But how to save each scene audiolistner to playerprefs .......  Please Please Explain a Little bit By Some Text  etc ...

Comment: Perhaps you don't have to change the audio every scene. Try just changing it when you press the button.

Comment: But My On /Off Button is located on  Main Menu Canves which is a scene one and these button control 20 other scene audio ..... what changes i do in 20 other scenes ?